# Missing of Conditional build step in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am using  **Jenkins 2.263.4**  version, i have need to use the conditional build step using the plugin "**conditional-buildstep"**    for it  installed  plugin version 1.4.1 but still, it is not appearing in the job's parameter dropdown

what am I missing?

**The details of plugin installed**

[image: details of plugin]

[image: job parameters]

Comment: Your screenshot shows the options to add another Choice Parameter. To see your plugin you need to add a Build Step as that's what the plugin is. (Also, did you restart or just install?)

Comment: Thanks a lot , so it is part of the Build steps